# Replace `{}` in string with hexadecimal values

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, hex

I have a string with random stuff in it, for example:

```
random_string = """

asdasdasd23123asdnos{}n
asdnoiaf{}aosndiasdasd
asd{}1239i123nig
hpodpfh{}askmdiasd
{asdasda
}asdasdasd
"""
```

I would like to replace every occurrence of `{}` in that string with a random hexadecimal value that is *different* from the previous values that replaced the other curly brackets.

I am using this function to generate hexadecimal values that are 100% random.

```
def get_random(n):
    out = set()
    while len(out) < n:
        out.add(binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(1)))
    return list(out)
```

I am missing a function or a loop, in which, the value of the hexadecimal is taken from the list `get_random(n)`, replacing `{}` in the string with the value of the hex from the list and printing out the output, and if there are any characters in the `{}`, they should be skipped.

I was using the module `re`, but not all values are random, there is a high chance some of the values are alike.

```
print(re.sub('{}', lambda _: binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(1)) + ' \\', random_string))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are patterns such as `{asdasda}` really ocurring or is this a copy-paste artifact?

Comment: @phaebz, it is a copy-paste artifact, the idea is the same though.

Comment: If there are really only `{}`s in there, then something such as  `random_string.format(*get_random(random_string.count('{}')))` would work.  Depending on the Python version you might need to `decode()` the `binascii.b2a_hex` return value to get a `str`.

Comment: how about the ` hexadecimal values` length? is it fixed?

Comment: @aircraft, yes. 2 characters.

Comment: if the origin str is `nos{}n` ， you want to change to `nosxxn` right? the `x` means random character,

Answer (score 2):

I think you are making this too complicated. The function [b2a_hex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_hex) generates 2 digit hex strings. Since that is only 256 (0->255) elements, just generate all of them, shuffle and yield those until they are gone:

```
def unique_hex():
    all_hex=['{:02x}'.format(e) for e in range(256)]
    random.shuffle(all_hex)
    for e in all_hex:
        yield e
    # returns None at this point. Add what you think it should do with no more
```

You can see each time invoked it is a randomized list of all unique hex digits between `00` and `ff`:

```
>>> list(unique_hex())
['95', '6a', '23', '1e', 'cb', '30', '78', '0f', 'e3', 'b2', '2d', '5c', '72', '7b', '9e', 'bd', '76', 'd8', '43', '6b', '0a', 'c6', '90', '0b', 'bf', 'a6', 'bc', 'd3', 'f3', '54', '15', 'b4', 'e9', '4a', 'b7', 'd5', 'cc', '2f', '00', 'f1', '64', 'f0', '2e', 'c0', 'b9', '9b', '7e', 'a9', '01', '03', '06', '27', 'b6', 'ab', '8d', '4b', '4d', 'f4', '19', 'df', '89', 'b0', '40', 'b1', '37', 'e2', '68', '5f', '39', 'ed', '16', 'a0', '5d', 'c3', 'a3', '1a', '13', '45', 'ce', 'c9', 'a5', '63', '60', '62', '75', '41', 'c4', '52', 'd2', 'cf', '61', '98', 'f9', 'c7', '18', 'ba', '34', '8c', '79', '81', '56', 'ff', 'd6', 'f8', '59', 'e7', '25', 'be', 'de', 'd1', '21', 'f7', '7c', '92', '67', '9a', '85', 'fd', 'fa', '07', '02', '49', '51', '87', '97', '38', '8a', 'b3', 'fe', 'da', '14', 'f6', '93', '8f', 'f5', '6c', '3d', 'c1', '70', '82', '55', 'ac', 'ae', '48', '11', '9c', 'ee', '1d', 'a2', '05', '6f', '71', '1f', 'ec', '58', 'ea', '9d', '8b', '0d', '83', '22', '4e', '66', 'cd', 'a1', 'ad', '3b', '88', '44', '53', 'e6', '3f', '47', 'fb', 'a4', '69', 'e8', '6d', '04', '7a', '20', '29', '84', 'af', '0c', 'c8', 'e4', '33', '74', 'ca', '65', 'c5', 'd4', '7d', '5a', 'f2', '96', '5b', 'e0', '32', '3e', '0e', 'a8', 'b5', '28', '36', '80', '08', 'a7', '09', '5e', '77', '3c', '46', '73', '91', '2a', '17', '99', 'fc', 'eb', '50', 'd0', '3a', '94', '24', '57', 'dc', '26', 'ef', '1b', 'd9', 'aa', '31', 'e1', '42', '1c', '2c', 'bb', '6e', 'db', 'c2', 'b8', '86', '9f', '12', '4f', 'd7', '4c', '2b', '10', '35', 'e5', '7f', 'dd', '8e']
>>> list(unique_hex())
['56', '48', '18', '39', '96', '60', 'b6', '82', '9c', '00', '79', '59', 'fb', 'e0', '81', '1f', 'df', 'f8', 'c7', '43', 'ee', '44', 'cc', '77', 'b7', '92', '75', 'd6', '1a', 'b5', 'f0', '6d', 'a0', 'f9', 'e6', 'e3', '6e', '99', '91', '41', '3c', 'dd', '87', 'c5', '8c', 'e4', '42', '34', '76', '47', '28', '58', '9a', '21', '0e', 'a4', 'b4', '51', '67', 'f2', '5b', '1d', '2d', '04', '2c', '19', 'b3', 'a9', 'f1', '7c', 'eb', '89', '70', 'fc', '14', 'bc', '02', '20', '4b', 'dc', 'c0', 'bf', 'e7', '62', '15', '49', 'a7', '13', 'b2', 'e2', 'f5', '66', '5c', 'd5', 'c1', 'ba', 'c9', '27', '4c', '7e', '24', 'd1', '2e', 'c8', '5d', '55', '83', '54', 'b1', 'ce', '29', '63', '11', '85', 'ff', '5a', 'a3', 'c6', '0b', '0a', 'fd', '65', '8d', 'ca', 'cd', '94', '74', '16', '71', '26', 'ad', '3f', 'ac', 'bb', 'd4', '08', 'b8', 'fa', '72', '31', '23', '37', '86', 'ed', '09', '1e', 'f6', 'cf', '50', '4e', '3e', 'a1', '80', '52', 'af', '03', 'f7', 'da', '95', '4f', '38', 'd8', 'b0', '17', '2b', '8e', '3a', 'fe', '78', 'c2', '45', 'ef', '32', 'de', 'c4', 'd7', '2f', '05', '36', '07', '46', '22', '6c', 'd0', '4d', '64', 'a2', '53', 'e1', '6b', '6f', 'c3', '12', '9b', 'd3', '25', '0f', 'e9', 'be', '35', 'a5', '30', '7f', '8f', '9e', '06', '0d', '8a', '5f', '68', '73', '57', '01', '2a', '4a', '88', 'f3', 'ae', 'aa', '9d', '97', '93', 'ec', 'd2', '7a', 'd9', 'db', '90', '84', '3d', '1b', 'f4', '6a', 'b9', '7b', '1c', 'a6', 'a8', '69', 'cb', '98', '7d', 'ab', '40', 'e8', '3b', 'ea', '10', 'e5', 'bd', '61', '33', '5e', '9f', '8b', '0c']
```

Then your regex becomes:

```
re.sub(r'\{\}', lambda m: next(unique_hex()), random_string)
```

Comment: Nice usage of generator and replacement function in `re.sub`.

Answer (score 0):

As hinted in my OP comment, if there are only `{}`s in there with no characters in between then the following works (tested with Python 3.6)

```py
import binascii
import os

random_string = """

asdasdasd23123asdnos{}n
asdnoiaf{}aosndiasdasd
asd{}1239i123nig
hpodpfh{}askmdiasd
{}asdasdasd
"""


def get_random(n):
    out = set()
    while len(out) < n:
        out.add(binascii.b2a_hex(os.urandom(1)).decode())
    return list(out)


print(random_string.format(*get_random(random_string.count('{}'))))
```

Output:

```html
asdasdasd23123asdnos51n
asdnoiaf50aosndiasdasd
asdf91239i123nig
hpodpfhb6askmdiasd
87asdasdasd
```

Comment: Can you confidently state that this produces new hex symbols with "a random hexadecimal value that is different from the previous values"? With your code, the chance of a duplicate goes up with the number of replacements. (Although OP also has a problem if there are more than 256 `{}` pairs; at that point his requirements can no longer fulfilled.)

Comment: I am using Python 2.7, also I only want to replace the characters when they are together, like this : `{}`, if there is a value in them they should be skipped.

Comment: Yes, as @usr2564301 wrote, this also does not solve my problem, I need the hex to be 100% random from the previous generations of random hex.

Comment: .. As I see it, to get a completely new random hex code you *must* pick from a list and then remove it. That's about the only way to get non-repeating random numbers. (Non-repeating within a sufficient small frame *only*.)

Comment: I think I now see the misunderstanding.  One needs to be careful with the wording _100% random_.  If the hex values were truly random (i.e. identically and independently distributed) then duplicates get indeed very likely after a number of realizations, see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).  What you ostensibly want is a random _permutation_ of all possible values which is nicely implemented in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48087075/1841459.  Also, with the requirement to only replace `{}` and skip `{.*}`, that answer is correct and more elegant.  Upvoted.